# RSpec - Expecting a 500 error after completing a JS prompt modal

Tags: error-handling, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm working on an interface where the user creates an entity and gives it a name via a simple JS alert prompt, and by design our back-end returns a 422 error if you submit a name that already exists in the database. My task is to then display a message on the front-end after this error happens.

I'm using `accept_prompt(with: "NAME")` to properly test the modal functionality, but I'm having a hard time telling Rspec to expect an error from the attempted POST that results from completing the prompt.

I've tried the code below and variations of it but it always seems like Rspec fails with "no error was raised" and then immediately fails with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR`(the exact error I'm trying to expect).

```
expect do
      accept_prompt(with: "NAME") do
        find(".selector .selector-item:first-child").click
      end
end.to raise_exception
```

I've even tried the below code to no avail:

```
expect accept_prompt(with: "NAME") do
      find(".selector .selector-item:first-child").click
end.to raise_exception
```

Is there some other known way to expect an error from a modal interaction in Rspec, or is it simply not possible?

Comment: You're confusing a backend error with a JS error -- Capybara is testing the browser side of this -- the browser doesn't have Ruby exceptions which what you're checking for.  Does the browser show an error page in your application? If so, that's what you should be checking for

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense-- thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We just resolved the issue, turns out the 500 error in the spec was caused by a problem with my spec configuration, unrelated to the 422 error that we expected to get and handle in the interface. Once we addressed that issue the 500 error went away and did not break the test, allowing us to continue running assertions against the frontend error validation.

So while there doesn't seem to be a way to actually catch and expect a *backend error* using Capybara, we didn't need to because that error wasn't supposed to be happening.